# Создание пагинации для таблицы на Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Использую `Bootstrap` для верстки. Есть необходимость создать `pagginator` для моих таблиц. Нашел [решение](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html), которое меня заинтересовало. Только не могу понять, как его внедрить на свою страницу, так как немного новичок в вебе.

Буду рад, если кто поможет с кодом. Возможно, кто-то подскажет другие варианты. Спасибо.

Вот пример моей страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../resources/images/logoGM_.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../../resources/html/jquery/table-sort.js"></script>
    <link href="/resources/html/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
<!-- Nav Panel-->


<!-- end Nav Panel-->


<div id="mainTable" class="container-fluid">
    <!-->
        <br>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed sort_table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>Номер </b></th>
                <th><b>Дата </b></th>
                <th><b>Тип </b></th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="searchable">
            <c:forEach items="${contracts}" var="contract">
               <tr class="danger">

                <td>${contract.docNum}</td>
                <td>${contract.startDate}</td>
                <td>${contract.agentType}</td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        (function ($) {
            $('#filter').keyup(function () {
                var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
                $('.searchable tr').hide();
                $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                    return rex.test($(this).text());
                }).show();
            })
        }(jQuery));
    });



    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто подключить css, js и одну строку кода.  Вы на главную страницу https://datatables.net/ зайдите, там вверху справа написано как подключать.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><b>Номер </b>
      </th>
      <th><b>Дата </b>
      </th>
      <th><b>Тип </b>
      </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="searchable">
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Яйца</td>
      <td>Круглые</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Куры</td>
      <td>Птицы</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="danger">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Гуси</td>
      <td>Плавающие</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. подключил так как вы указали, добавил js получаю ошибку в консоле "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined" не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: разобрался. спасибо!